The `.tint(_:)` modifier does not work on conditionally rendered buttons
List {
    TextField("...", text: $aVariable)
        .swipeActions {
            if aVariable != "" {
                Button(action: {
                    // ...
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.bin.fill")
                })
                .tint(.red)
            }
        }
}

The .tint(.red) here should change the button background color to red, but the if statement outside the button seems to prevent the color change.
How can this issue be resolved?

I cannot reproduce it, it works fine on the Simulator 17.0.1.

What device/platform are you testing on? You've tagged both iOS and watchOS, does that mean you're experiencing the issue on both? If so, are you testing on simulator or device? What OS versions?

I’m working on watchOS, both simulator and device can reproduce this problem.
